# Only for show_pdf action param is not able to pass using jquery script

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

i am just trying to pass params like this while pdf generation

in show_pdf.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var header_height = $("#page-yield").height();
    $.post('design_custom_reports/show_pdf',{height:header_height});
  });
</script>
```

I tried the same code in index.html.erb it works fine i could pass params in index action but only in show_pdf action i could not pass params during pdf generation i am using wicked-pdf gem for pdf generation and i have used target blank to view the pdf in another tab, i can able to generate pdf but param is not passed i think $.post is not working while pdf generation then how to pass params to show_pdf action using jquery

so can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Wicked PDF does not support the use of UI widgets, in this case browser widgets such as pop-ups. Are you expecting a pop-up to appear when the user opens the PDF from their desktop? Of course not. Then why are you triggering a Javascript alert in the first place? Remove the `alert()` and barring any other bugs in your code the PDF will be generated.

Comment: actually i dont want alert there but iam trying with some other stuff like                                                    <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var header_height = $("#custom_report").height();
    $.post('design_custom_reports/index',{lat:header_height});
  });
</script>           i am sending params to index action which is not happening

Comment: Actually i dont want alert there but iam trying with some other stuff like                                                    <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var header_height = $("#custom_report").height();
    $.post('design_custom_reports/show_pdf',{height:header_height});
  });
</script>           i am sending param to show_pdf action which is not happening param height is not passed to that action     i will get pdf report here but params is not passed

Comment: Hard to debug from just your messages. Maybe you need to bump up the `--javascript-delay` flag in `wkhtmltopdf`? That is, you're loading external jQuery but maybe its not waiting for it to load and you're getting errors that you don't see(?). Try running `wkhtmltopdf` from the command line with `--debug-javascript` and see what kind of error output you get.